# How to model opcodes effectively for a language VM?

Tags: language-design, virtual-machine

I am learning about building a language VM with the long-term goal of writing an own language.

For guidance, I am looking at this [LC3 tutorial](https://www.jmeiners.com/lc3-vm/) by Justin Meiners and [Building a Language VM](https://blog.subnetzero.io/post/building-language-vm-part-01/) by Fletcher Haynes. (I have also previously gone through the Nand2Tetris course).

In the LC3 approach, I note that the opcodes and their parameters are contained in a single 16 byte instruction, while in the latter, the parameters can be contained in subsequent words so, depending on the opcode, the VM will then consume further words from the program memory.

Is there an advantage to going either way? Would the former approach be slower, because you first have to bit-shift the opcode and parameters out of the instruction? (I assume this is sort of modeled after how you would have to do it on a physical machine).

I assume that there is no real limitation in building a language VM, because you're not tied to the parameters of a physical machine, so would there be any advantages in following the approach demonstrated by LC3?

Comment: maybe convenience

Comment: You are very much limited to the parameters of every targeted physical machine. In fact, you're limited to the subset of parameters that they all have in common. Given every targeted machine is Turing complete that limitation largely impacts performance. It's hard to take advantage of op codes and hardware that you can't be sure exist. If you're lucky you can provide a language that expresses needs in a way that can be optimized when those features exist to be exploited, and without failing when they don't.

Comment: @candied_orange Thanks for the info. My desire is to build more of a DSL than a language really. It is inspired by SAP's ABAP language (more of a DSL too) which they use to build their business applications. It also compiles to bytecode for its own VM which, based on what I have seen, has a vast range of opcodes (even for executing SQL commands), so it seems the VM and language go very much hand in hand and the VM is highly tailored to the language and just executes some C routines in most cases. That's kind of my goal.

Comment: @candied_orange ... but I still need to dig quite a bit to learn how to effectively build a VM and model things like memory and how to make an efficient bytecode representation etc. to support those functions.

Comment: Lots of trade-offs is involved! But if you are building your own VM I would recommend having parameters in separate words, since it is simpler to implement and the instruction set is easier to change and evolve. Settling on a compact format with bitmasks for parameters will make it more difficult to evolve.

Comment: @JacquesB, thanks for the feedback. What then would be the advantage of encoding everything into a single word, other than perhaps for teaching and demonstration purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Practical instruction sets tend to use variable length instructions, which has a number of advantageous consequences:

- You can include immediate values directly with the instructions, without having to load the constants from a data section or constants table. For example, consider how you compile `x + 7` – where does that value `7` come from? Your instructions might have enough space for small values, but what if the value is as large as your instructions, for example a floating-point constant? With variable-length instructions this isn't a problem, as you can have an instruction that just reads the next couple of bytes as data.
- You can make your instruction set more compact. Frequently used instructions should be short and dense, and it is OK if more rarely used or more expensive instructions are longer. Similarly, text encoding nowadays tends to prefer the variable-length UTF-8 over the simpler but more wasteful UTF-16 or UTF-32 encodings.

There are limitations though:

- You can't know where an instruction starts without decoding all previous instructions. This makes debugging more difficult, and a faulty implementation could be vulnerable to some security issues. In some cases, you might use special encodings (like UTF-8 uses) so that you can always tell whether a given byte could be the start of a new instruction.
- Decoding instructions is a bit more complex now, though this probably won't be a huge issue.
- Variable-size instructions make it possible to have many more instructions, thus potentially encouraging over-complex designs.

However, you might not need any encoded instructions at all. Finding such an encoding is necessary if you want a serialization format for code, so that you can compile the code to your bytecodes in one process, and then execute the code in another. If you're just writing an interpreter, and don't have any ambitions regarding performance or memory use, I'd recommend:

- Use a programming language that has built-in support for discriminated unions, e.g. OCaml, Rust, arguably C++ with `std::variant`. Or maybe, if you really don't care about memory density, use OOP to model instructions.
- Then, keep these enums/objects in a plain array. This corresponds to fixed-length instructions, but you won't have to do any further decoding.
- You can use any features of your host language to store data in these instructions. For example, they can have pointers to well-typed data, instead of offsets into some table.
- In some cases, you might not need any Opcode representation at all, if a tree-walking interpreter is sufficient for your language.

If your eventual goal is to create your own language, I would suggest leaving VM/interpreter details for later. Focusing on these aspects can be important when you want to optimize everything for performance, but if you start with that you might be optimizing for the wrong things, and might be implementing VM-level semantics that make it unnecessarily difficult to implement your language. For example, note how the JVM instruction set is well-tuned for Java programs, but would make it very difficult to execute C-style code.

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I have not considered the option of designing my language top-down, but it's perhaps worth looking at it from that perspective.

Comment: @mydoghasworms Something I can greatly recommend for PL projects is to start with a simple end-to-end test case, like “`print(1 + 1)` outputs `2`”. Ideally in the form of doctests so that you build a testable manual for your language. This lets you prototype your syntax and semantics, and later makes it safe to try out optimizations like a higher-performance VM design.

Comment: One nice feature that UTF-8 has is that you can tell the length of an encoded code point just by looking at the first byte of its UTF-8 sequence.  Might be useful for a variable-length instruction set.